# Ubuntu 18.04 端末起動時に必ず表示される「そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません」

Tags: ubuntu, 端末

こんにちは、初投稿です。よろしくお願いします。
Ubuntu 18.04で端末起動時に必ず、

```
bash: export　PATH=/Users/user_name/anaconda3/bin:/home/kazuki/anaconda3/bin:/home/kazuki/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません
```

と表示されます。anacondaインストール時にpathの設定がうまくいかず素人なりに調べてなんとかしたのですが、たぶんこれが影響しているんだと思います。
この表示をなくすために.bash_profileや.bashrcの編集を試みましたが、.bash_profileをvimでひらいても新規ファイル扱いで何も表示されないし、.bashrcにはanacondaのPATHが載っていましたが

```sh
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/kazuki/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/kazuki/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/kazuki/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/kazuki/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

このような感じでどうもこれはあの余計な表示の原因ではないように思います。
端末起動時の余計な表示をなくすにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: 先頭の `/Users/user_name/anaconda3/bin` が怪しいですね。これは Mac 用の設定で、しかもユーザー名が設定されていないように見えます。`.bashrc` の内容を `user_name` で検索すると何かひっかかりませんか？　また、念のため `/home/kazuki/anaconda3` が存在するかどうか、端末で `ls /home/kazuki/anaconda3` を実行して確かめた結果を本文に追記していただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: exportとPATHの間のスペースが全角スペース(0x3000)なのも気になります…

Comment: `~$ ls home/kazuki/anaconda3
ls: 'home/kazuki/anaconda3' にアクセスできません: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません`

Comment: `export　PATH=/Users/user_name/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`

Comment: home/kazuki/anaconda3はlsコマンドでも、GUIで探してみてもやはりありませんでした。また、`user_name`で検索すると`# <<< conda initialize <<<`のあとに、上記の`export`から始まる文字列がありました。

Comment: 確かにhinaloeさんの言うとおりですね。`.bashrc`を昨日今日知ったばかりの私の感覚では、この冒頭の`bash: export　PATH=/Users/user_name/anaconda3/bin:/home/kazuki/anaconda3/bin:/home/kazuki/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:`が、`.bashrc`などのファイルにそのまま記入されているだろうという認識なのですが、目視で探す限りでは見当たらなかったので質問させていただきました。

Comment: 試しにバックアップを取った上で`export　PATH=/Users/user_name/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`を`.bashrc`から削除してみたところ、問題の文字列が表示されなくなりました！`conda`や`python`の`PATH`にも特に影響はないようです。おふた方、助言いただきありがとうございました。

Comment: @kazuttyoboy 解決したようで何よりです。このコメントの内容を自己回答も出来ますので、自己回答いただいて、後日承認して下さい。そうすると質問が未解決状態ではなくなります。